# VB.net parsing HTML TV listings

Tags: vb.net, parsing, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have the following HTML code grabbed from a tv listings page:

```
<div class="channel_row">
   <span class="channel">                            
    <div class="logo"><img src ="/images/channel_logos/WGNAMER.png" /></div>                            
    <p><strong>2</strong><br />
    WGNAMER
    </p>
   </span>                          

   <span class="time" style="width:0.0px;padding:0;height:42px;">
     <div style="margin:10px">
       <a class="thickbox" style="" href="/tv/info/?program_id=49909&height=260&width=612" title="WGN News at Nine">WGN News at Nine</a>                                     
       <p class="schedule_flags"><strong class="new_flag">New</strong>, <strong class="cc_flag">CC</strong>, <strong class="stereo_flag">Stereo</strong></p>
     </div>
   </span>                          
   <span class="time" style="width:245.6px;padding:0;height:42px;">
     <div style="margin:10px">
       <a class="thickbox" style="" href="/tv/info/?program_id=49910&height=260&width=612" title="America&#39;s Funniest Home Videos">America&#39;s Funniest Home Videos</a>                                     
       <p class="schedule_flags"><strong class="cc_flag">CC</strong>, <strong class="stereo_flag">Stereo</strong></p>
     </div>
   </span>                          
</div>
```

And it just keeps looping with **channel_row** over and over again...

Now i have set up some VB code with the help of **HtmlAgilityPack** in hopes to have a quick and easy way to loop through all these classes and grab **logo image, TV channel, station name, HREF of more show description & show title**

So in the above example the parse would look like:

```
/images/channel_logos/WGNAMER.png
2
WGNAMER
/tv/info/?program_id=49909&height=260&width=612
WGN News at Nine

/tv/info/?program_id=49910&height=260&width=612
America&#39;s Funniest Home Videos
```

My VB code is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim htmlString As String = "<div class=""channel_row"">" & _
                   "<span class=""channel"">" & _
                           "<div class=""logo""><img src =""/images/channel_logos/WELF.png"" /></div>" & _
                       "<p><strong>13</strong><br />" & _
  "WELF" & _
                       "</p>" & _
                   "</span>" & _
                       "<span class=""time"" style=""width:245.6px;padding:0;height:42px;"">" & _
                           "<div style=""margin:10px"">" & _
                               "<a class=""thickbox"" style="""" href=""/tv/info/?program_id=35424&height=260&width=612"" title=""Praise the Lord"">Praise the Lord</a>" & _
                               "<p class=""schedule_flags""><strong class=""cc_flag"">CC</strong></p>" & _
                           "</div>" & _
                       "</span>" & _
                       "<span class=""time"" style=""width:122.8px;padding:0;height:42px;"">" & _
                           "<div style=""margin:10px"">" & _
                               "<a class=""thickbox"" style="""" href=""/tv/info/?program_id=35425&height=260&width=612"" title=""ACLJ This Week"">ACLJ This Week</a> " & _
                               "<p class=""schedule_flags""><strong class=""cc_flag"">CC</strong></p>" & _
                           "</div>" & _
                       "</span>" & _
                       "<span class=""time"" style=""width:122.8px;padding:0;height:42px;"">" & _
                           "<div style=""margin:10px"">" & _
                               "<a class=""thickbox"" style="""" href=""/tv/info/?program_id=35426&height=260&width=612"" title=""Full Flame"">Full Flame</a>  " & _
                               "<p class=""schedule_flags""><strong class=""cc_flag"">CC</strong></p>" & _
                           "</div>" & _
                       "</span>" & _
                       "<span class=""time"" style=""width:0.0px;padding:0;height:42px;"">" & _
                           "<div style=""margin:10px"">" & _
                               "<a class=""thickbox"" style="""" href=""/tv/info/?program_id=35427&height=260&width=612"" title=""Secrets: Kim Clement"">Secrets: Kim Clement</a>                                     " & _
                               "<p class=""schedule_flags""></p>" & _
                           "</div>" & _
                       "</span>" & _
               "</div>"


    Dim doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
    Dim htmlDocument As IHTMLDocument2 = New HTMLDocumentClass()
    htmlDocument.write(htmlString)
    htmlDocument.close()

    doc.LoadHtml(String.Format(htmlString))
    Dim res = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='channel_row']")

    For Each item In res
        Dim firstDiv = item.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='channel']")
        Dim content1 = firstDiv.ChildNodes(0).InnerText.Trim()
        Dim content2 = firstDiv.ChildNodes(1).InnerText.Trim()
        Dim content4 = item.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='myclass2']")
    Next
End Sub
```

Currently the error is on line **Dim content1 = firstDiv.ChildNodes(0).InnerText.Trim()** which says:

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Any help would be great!

**UPDATE**

With newest code suggestions:

```
Dim doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(htmlString)

Dim all = new Dictionary(of String, Object)()
For Each channel In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='channel_row']") 
    Dim info = new Dictionary(of String, Object)()

    With channel

        info!Logo    = .SelectSingleNode(".//img").Attributes("src").Value
        info!Channel = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(0).InnerText
        info!Station = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(2).InnerText

        info!Shows = From tag In .SelectNodes(".//a[@class='thickbox']")
                     Select New With {.Show = tag.Attributes("title").Value, .Link = tag.Attributes("href").Value}

    End With

    all.Add(info!Station, info)
Next 

all.Dump()
```

There are 3 errors:

1) On line **Select New With {.Show = Tag.Attributes("title").Value, .Link = Tag.Attributes("href").Value}**

The error is: **'Select Case' must end with a matching 'End Select'.**

2) On line **all.Add(info!Station, info)**

The error is: **Statements and labels are not valid between 'Select Case' and first 'Case'.**

3) On line **all.Dump()**

The error is: **'Dump' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Object)'.**

Comment: Still looking for a working solution.

Comment: Be sure you have the namespace `System.Linq` imported. As I already said, you can use any other type instead of the anoymous one. Also, I already told you that the `Dump()` extension method is part of LINQPad, so if you compile the code in Visual Studio (or anywhere outside LINQPad), it's obvious that the method will not be found. You also obviously don't need that call, since all that the method does is just dumping the object to the output window of LINQPad.

Comment: @Mr.Steak Alright got it working with importing that but how do i get the values from Shows to display? I already tried msgbox(info.Shows) and also msgbox(info.Shows.show) but i can not get anything from that-only errors. How do i get the show and the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no HtmlAgilityPack expert, but how about:

```
Dim htmlString As String = "<div class=""channel_row"">" &  _ ...

Dim doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(htmlString)

Dim all = new Dictionary(of String, Object)()
For Each channel In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='channel_row']") 
    Dim info = new Dictionary(of String, Object)()

    With channel

        info!Logo    = .SelectSingleNode(".//img").Attributes("src").Value
        info!Channel = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(0).InnerText
        info!Station = .SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(2).InnerText

        info!Shows = From tag In .SelectNodes(".//a[@class='thickbox']")
                     Select New With {.Show = tag.Attributes("title").Value, .Link = tag.Attributes("href").Value}

    End With

    all.Add(info!Station, info)
Next 

all.Dump()
```

[image]

Comment: There is a problem with **Select Tuple.Create** and **info.Dump()** and **shows.ToList().Dump()**?

Comment: Could you explain another way of doing this other than using that Tuple?

Comment: That also doesn't seem to loop thru each id of **channel_row** It just does it once and thats all.

Comment: @StealthRT You didn't say which framework version you are using. `Tuple` was added in .NET 4.0, so I guess you are using 3.5 or something. I replaced the use of `Tuple` in my code with an anonymous type, but you could use any other type you want of course. Maybe just create a class to hold the values, but it would bloat up this example.

Comment: @StealthRT The `Dump()` extension method is part of [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), which you can use to run .NET code without Visual Studio. You should give it a try. My code worked for the sample html you provided; nonetheless, I updated it to loop through multiple **channel_row** elements with a `For Each` loop, as you can see.

Comment: Yes i am using framework 3.5. I still have to errors when using your newest code. Check OP for those.

Comment: Alright got it working with importing that but how do i get the values from **Shows** to display? I already tried **msgbox(info.Shows)** and also **msgbox(info.Shows.show)** but i can not get anything from that-only errors. How do i get the show and the link?

Comment: @StealthRT Querying the data from HTML using HtmlAgilityPack is one thing, how to process this data is another. You should spend some time thinking about what you want to do with the data, how to process it, and probably how to present it to the user (or whatever you want to do with the data). I use `Dictionary`s and the anonymous type in my example solely be able to simply output it LINQPad. You propably want to create some classes to "store" the extracted data, like a class called `Station` with properties like `Channel` and `Shows`, whereas `Shows` is a collection of a class called...

Comment: ... `Show`, which in turn has the properties `Show Name` and `Link` or something like that. It depends on *what you want to do with your data*. The code extracts the data fine, it's up to you what you want to do with it. If you're not familiar with anonymous types, just skip it and use a `Dictionary` instead. Or create, as I already said, a custom class.